Remove duplicate (almost) rows based on value in the distinct column
Consider this result in SQL Server:
ID    Check
-----------
9052    N
9052    Y
2049    N
2049    Y
6940    N
6940    Y
7941    N
8118    N
8187    N

How can I delete the duplicate ID rows and leave only Y in Check column if there is at least one Y for the same ID. If there are IDs only with N, keep them. I have quite a few other columns not displayed in the example. So the expected results would be:
ID    Check
------------
9052    Y
2049    Y
6940    Y
7941    N
8118    N
8187    N


If there are IDs only with N, keep them, what if there is the same id multiple times with N only, for example id 8187 is repeated 4 times with N, you need to keep the 4 records or only 1 ?

@Ergest Basha in my case they are filtered out by DISTINCT. So I only needed to get rid of duplicated IDs with Ns if there are also same IDs with Y.

CHECK is a reserved word so I would avoid that column name. At any rate, since Y > N then you can use MAX.
select 
 id, 
 max(check_col) as check_col
from table1
group by id
order by id




id
check_col




2049
Y


6940
Y


7941
N


8118
N


8187
N


9052
Y



fiddle

Your comment is 100% valid.  Perhaps rather than changing the column name, you could offer an alternative   ...   [check]    Either way +1

@Isolated thanks for the answer and a valid point
